# mysql left join column reorganizing

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have a table named `application_user` which have a field named `id`. Another table named `voucher_info` which has a field named `maker_id`. Now I want to `LEFT JOIN` the `application_user` table with `voucher_info` table using `maker_id` with `id` ? But this error is shown instead:

```
Error Code: 1054
            Unknown column 'application_user.id' in 'on clause'
```

Can anyone please help me on this please ? Here is my code below :

```
LEFT JOIN application_user AS maker
    ON(voucher_info.maker_id = application_user.id)
```

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have that column. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to

```
ON (voucher_info.maker_id = maker.id)
```

Once you alias a table, you can only reference it by the alias.